# Delete list of files read from txt

Tags: php, file, delete-file

I wrote a small clean up php-script that is supposed to automatically delete a list of files on my server. The file list is a simple txt-file ("3.txt") that contains one file entry per line.

Format of 3.txt:

```
folder/filename1.fileending
folder/filename2.fileending
folder/filename3.fileending
folder/filename4.fileending
```

For some reason the script seems to read the file list properly, but only manages to delete the very last file successfully ("folder/filename4.fileending"). I assumed that the line break might screw things up and filtered it out to no avail. I also tried to use a Unix line break, also without success.

Clean up script:

```
<?php
$cleanlist = fopen("3.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file list!");

while(!feof($cleanlist)) {

$temp = rtrim(fgets($cleanlist), "\r\n");

    if(!file_exists($temp))
      {
      echo ("Error deleting "). $temp . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
      unlink($temp);
      echo ("Deleted ") . $temp . "<br>";
      }
}
fclose($cleanlist);
?>
```

I also tried putting "unlink($temp)" behind the If statement so that it gets executed every time in case there's a screw up in the condition itself, but the result was just the same. I'm at my wits end. Does anyone have an idea why my script can't successfully delete any file save for the last on the list?

Update: Now the script worked out of the blue! I assume my hosting provider played a role in that...or may be not. Still, thank you to everyone who contributed. This was my very first php-script and thanks to your suggestions I learned a lot about error tracing in php :)

Comment: What is the output when you run the script? You have several "echo's" which could give hint.

Comment: It probably is the line ending, maybe instead of trim `"\r\n"` , try `trim` with `PHP_EOL` constant. Try also trim, not just rtrim.

Comment: I think `file()` and `foreach` would much easier to use imho.

Comment: @etalon11: The output is always:

Error deleting folder/filename1.fileending
Error deleting folder/filename2.fileending
Error deleting folder/filename3.fileending
Deleted folder/filename4.fileending

Comment: @Jessica: I actually used trim() before resorting to rtrim(). It didn't work either. I'll give PHP_EOL a shot.

Comment: Okay so the problem is not with the `unlink` then, the problem is at finding if the file exists. You can do `var_dump()` on the name of the file to see exactly what is in it, with your current output you could be missing the fact that there is still whitespace.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. It might be a permissions issue for folder and/or files. You could also try removing the `\r` - `$temp = rtrim(fgets($cleanlist), "\n");` if not on a Windows platform, but should work either way. I'm on a Linux server.

Comment: I also checked your code and it is working. Check your "3.txt" or your permissions

Comment: @Jessica: PHP_EOL produced the same result. I used var_dump and realized that file_exist doesn't produce a value except for the very last file, where it assumes the value of "1" as it should with every other file. The other variables look okay. There doesn't seem to be any corruption in them that would explain this behavior.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I also thought it might be a permission issue at first and relaxed permissions on all files, but it didn't help. Also, even without changing permissions, the files do get deleted as long as they are listed last in the file list which pretty much should rule out a permission issue, or else deletion would fail on all entries.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii: I did that and the script took considerably longer to run, yet no errors were displayed. : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, just advice on using file and foreach.

Like I said in my comment, I think you're taking some unnecessary steps.  `file()` puts each line of a file into an array for you and makes it pretty easy.

```
$list = file('3.txt');
if ($list === false) {
    die('Cannot open file');
}

foreach($list as $file) {
    if (unlink($file)) { 
        echo ("Deleted ") . $file . "<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo ("Error deleting "). $file. "<br>";
    }
}
// Zero out file?
#file_put_contents('3.txt', '');
```

I hope you make sure that 3.txt has limited write abilities or you make it a relative path though.  I can see some malicious intent otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for writing up a more efficient suggestion. It behaves just like my version: last file gets deleted, the rest is not. It goes without saying that the txt-file will have its write permissions locked :)

Btw, you forgot a semicolon after "$list = file('3.txt')" ;)

Comment: @Zerobinary99, I have fixed that, thanks for pointing it out.  Try adding `echo (is_readable($file)) ? 'Readable' : 'Not Readable';` after foreach.  Might give you some insight on the permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The script is working now for some strange reason. I already updated the question regarding that fact. I'm not quite sure what happened, but I suspect my hoster changed some settings on his end. I actually switched to your version of the script since I like its cleaner look, so I'll accept it as answer even though technically the problem solved itself. Thanks for introducing me to some new interesting php statements :)